# Toroid coating got scratched

Tags: magnetics, toroid

Will there be any performance effect if the torroid coating gets scratched?[image]

Comment: How high voltage are you running?

Comment: I would run it at maybe 20volts 200khz

Comment: Is this going to be an EMI filter, or a transformer, or an output inductor?  What kind of topology are you building?

Comment: Then no issues! If the crack is sharp O would consider filing it down first.

Comment: This will be the used in boost converter @Nick Alexeev

Comment: Nah its just a very small scratch @winny

Comment: @Hritural  Powdered iron will have large losses at the kinds of current and frequency which it will see in a 200kHz boost.  This is ferrite territory.

Comment: Its a sendust core ..part number is MS-106125-2 .

Answer (score 3):

From the physics standpoint, broken coating will not affect performance.

Broken coating may cause a few practical inconveniences.

- This looks like an iron powder core with an enamel coating.  The coating simply prevents rusting.  So, the core will rust where the coating is damaged.  (Ferrites usually aren't coated.)
- Broken coating may have sharp edges which cut through the magnet wire enamel.  (You could smooth the sharp edges with sandpaper.)